# JSoup: Replacing entire div

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using Jsoup and want to replace and entire div, say

```
<div id="1"> asda </div>
```

with

```
<div id="2"> qwe  </div>
```

I found methods to replace innerHtml of a div, but how can I replace an entire div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Element div` is the element you want to change:

**Solution 1:** Rewrite the tag:

```
div.text("qwe").attr("id", "2"); // Change text and attribute
```

**Solution 2:** Replace with another Tag:

```
Element newDiv = doc.createElement("div"); // Create the new element
newDiv.attr("id", "2"); // Set it's values
newDiv.text("qwe");

div.replaceWith(newDiv); // Replace element with new one
```

Comment: What if div is the element which contains "<div id="1"> asda </div>" as one of its child (or grandchild or grand-grand child etc.) divs?

Comment: If the element has further child elements you don't have to care about this in *solution 1* (since you only change the elements values), but if you use *solution 2* you can retrieve the childs of the element and set it to the new one.